# Logged out when hit home link in drupal 7.19?

Tags: navigation

Noticed I am auto logged out or at least that is how it appears with the admin bar disappearing and login form visible when I hit the home link.

If I go from logged out home page to another page I appear logged back in.

I am on drupal 7.19 and it resides in a folder set up as a subdirectory.

drupal.mysite.com

the folder is at drupal.mysite.com/drupal

This only occurs when I am navigating about without www prefix and does NOT happen when navigating about with www prefix. My site can be accessed either way but currently advertising as without prefix. The www is more secure obviously but need both to work.

Comment: Have you checked the .htaccess settings?

Comment: my .htaccess had to be removed because it interferes with clean urls. Instead I use httpd.conf and settings.php but you are right I think. But don't want to choose between prefix or not, both should work.

Comment: In that case, this is very likely a problem with the configuration in your httpd.conf and settings.php.  If your hosting provider offers Drupal hosting, I would ask them first about what may be the problem; as the provider, they know your set up much better than anyone else.

Comment: I am not sure why .htaccess would interfere with clean url. it is meant for that.

Comment: Well .htaccess uses more memory to run and the httpd.conf together with settings and php.ini can do the work between them. But the .htaccess code for prefix or no prefix with www is an either or statement so not code that I can use even tho could use if i wanted added to settings file.

Comment: Patrick is right that it is in .htaccess code but i cannot use that code because i don't want either or nothing which is only way that coded argument works.

Comment: Mohammed, I put the clean urls statement in bottom of settings file and it works fine.

Comment: why is my question marked down- anyway of finding out?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is well stated here http://drupal.org/node/110478

Had I spent a little more time reading I would not have had to ask this question.
Also I can see now it is making it so no matter which prefix you use the cookie will stick.

Comment: actually no , in the end this was all about the browser not being up to date in safari.